# Why auspicious things not performed in Aadi and Margashirsha?

Tags: scripture, belief, bhagavata-purana, bhavishya-purana

Auspicious things like marriage, upanayanam, grihapravesh etc are not performed in the months of Aadi & Margashirsha. Both the months are prescribed for bhajans and visiting temples as per Hindu belief. Any supports from bhagavathams or scriptures why is it so?